# Excel VBA Should I use Arrays or a Queue or Other? w/ Criteria passed as parameters

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, queue

I have a data set with 2500 rows and 65 columns. I have a specific set of criteria than involves Greater/Less than `>` / `<` ,`AND`, `OR`, and `Like` Operators that needs to be evaluated on EACH row.

For example:

If Column 2 equals `1007001500` OR `1007000510` AND Column 3 `> 25` AND `< 25` AND Column 4 equals `"asset"` AND Column 5 equals `"S"` Then I need to assign a unique value for this row or in other words I need to classify this row into the 1 of 10 categories I have for this 2500 R x 65 C data set (which is an imported excel file).

I am fairly familiar with 1D and 2D arrays and I have gotten to the point of importing all the Logic into either 1D or 2D array. I am at this point deciding whether to evaluate the logic in one long 1D Array String across 1 Row and 1 Column or a larger 2D array with each categories' logic segregated into a separate row within the 2D array.

But I have also arrived at the question, **is there a better data structure approach?** I have briefly research Excel VBA `Queues` and have turned here for more expertise.

My data set will always have the same Columns labels I can used to evaluate upon. However **my logic criteria is always subject to change by the user of the macro.** So I am looking for a way to basically pass all my criteria as parameters to a data structure.

Comment: It sounds like your "unique value" is just a user-specified formula in a 66th column.  (And Column 3 can't be both > 25 **and** < 25.)

Comment: While @KenWhite is correct, assigning all of the values into a 2D array and subsequently processing 'in-memory' is several factors faster then looping through rows and cells on a worksheet.

Comment: btw, if you have working code and require optimization, delete this post and repost at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel).

Comment: It seems you have 10 groups; with multiple rows within each group.  If that is the case, I would suggest that you work with a VBA array and a collection or dictionary object, where each item is a collection of the rows for the particular group.  You can then output in whatever fashion.  As @Jeeped writes, using VBA arrays is much faster than processing from the worksheet -- in my experience often 10x or more faster.

Answer (score 1):

An array/matrix is a good way to handle data in VBA. Here is the way that I store such data:

```
LRL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'COunts the rows
LCL = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Counts the columns

ReDim Level_Array_Unsort(LRL, LCL) 'Dimensionalizes the matrix

'This stores the data
For i = 1 To LRL
    For j = 1 To LCL
        Level_Array_Unsort(i, j) = Cells(i, j)
    Next j
Next
```

Comment: Try this instead:  `Dim Level_Array_Unsort : Level_Array_Unsort = Range(cells(1,1), cells(LRL,LCL))`  No loops and will execute much faster. See Chip Pearsons [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRan)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld makes sense, hwever if he wanted to filter data with an **IF** statement then maybe it can help to do it all in one loop when he takes in the data.

Comment: I don't think so. You are doing one read vs `i*j` reads.  Read it all in, then loop through the array with the testing algorithm.